# how can i make generic search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table in that I am using a search bar I need to make a search to be generic for all fields if any of the value will get a match that result will show what I did I made just for one field but I need to make it for all field so I need to make like whatever value is present that all will get check like generic search like for example if I search using **name, id, module**, etc all that value will use for search bar

```
[{
  "isConsole": true,
  "taskStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "taskName": "G-csv_download-25",
  "id": 463,
  "module": "Management",
  "subModule": "Grid",
  "taskId": "1fc0d5a7-834a-4906-8448-16835e8838b0",
  "projectId": 42,
  "createdAt": "2023-01-21T05:56:50.184965Z",
  "size": 0.20800000000000002,
  "failureMessage": null
}, {
  "isConsole": true,
  "taskStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "taskName": "G-csv_download-26",
  "id": 464,
  "module": "Management",
  "subModule": "Grid",
  "taskId": "2724fcbf-d25b-424f",
  "projectId": 42,
  "createdAt": "2023-01-21T06:02:48.557536Z",
  "size": 0.20800000000000002,
  "failureMessage": null
}, {
  "isConsole": true,
  "taskStatus": "SUCCESS",
  "taskName": "G-csv_download-27",
  "id": 465,
  "module": "Management",
  "subModule": "Grid",
  "taskId": "26642fb3-1593-4e0d-b276-901bb7e729c3",
  "projectId": 42,
  "createdAt": "2023-01-21T10:31:30.965508Z",
  "size": 0.20800000000000002,
  "failureMessage": null
}]
this is for single field
  const searchBasedFilter = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      downloads.filter((data) =>
        searchData
          ? data.subModule?.toLowerCase().includes(searchData?.toLowerCase())
          : data
      ),
    [searchData, downloads]
  );
```

Comment: how about go through all the values of the objects in the array ? or first go through id's if not found , then use name's and goes on

Comment: like in search bar if i search using id then it will filter based on id if I search based on name then it will filter based on name like that

Comment: i have many field

Answer (score 1):

To make the search generic for all fields, you can use the Object.values() method to extract all the values of the object, and then use Array.prototype.some() method to check if any of the values match the search query.

Something like:

```
const searchBasedFilter = React.useMemo(
() =>
  downloads.filter((data) =>
    searchData
      ? Object.values(data).some((value) =>
          value?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchData?.toLowerCase())
        )
      : data
  ),
[searchData, downloads]
);
```

This will check all the values of the object, whether it is a string or number, and will check if the search query is present in any of the values of the object.